# Updating data in a json file that deployed in heroku

Tags: python, git, flask, heroku, postman

I am new to the heroku ,git and postman. I have created a simple python program that performs create, delete, update and get operations in a json file containing employee data. I have deployed my project folder in heroku by using following commands,

1. heroku login
2. git init
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "first commit"
5. heroku git:remote --app
6. git push heroku master

The project is deployed successfully. But the thing is when I send the create operation request from postman api, it successfully gives response but data is not getting update in my json file. I tried this command,

1. git pull https://git.heroku.com/<my_app>.git

I want to pull changes to my json file which is in my computer.

Comment: You should be using a proper storage backend like postgres to store this information.  On heroku [the disk is Ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku) meaning that changes to files do not survive application restarts.  Even if that isn't your current problem, it will become a problem eventually.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it.